# Bug in Suggested Edit Review stats

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits, statistics

When viewing a specific suggested edit review (accessed on the `History` tab in the review queue), you can see the reviewers' approve/reject statistics. I noticed that my stats reported here are clearly wrong: I've completed almost 1,200 suggested edits reviews, but it says I've approved ~780 and rejected just 1. I've rejected a LOT more than that. Plus, the total number of reviews doesn't match. I've noticed similar weirdness for other users with a high number of reviews.

For example:

[image]

This isn't a big deal, but it's certainly wrong. Just a heads up.

Comment: Also, there's a pluralization error :)